# How to get the selected payment method when the "sales_order_save_after" event is fired?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, sales-order, place-order

I'm developing an observable that listen to the `sales_order_save_after` event.

I have the order information executing `$observer->getEvent()->getOrder()` but i cannot get the payment method selected (cash on delivery or check/money order, etc).

I did try with `$order->getPayment()->getMethod()` but this works only when the order already has been payed. (And I need to know what payment method was selected when the order was placed).

Thanx in advance

Comment: $payment = $order->getPayment();
$method = $payment->getMethod();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code in your Observer to get payment method data

**Method 1**

```
$payment = $order->getPayment();
$method = $payment->getMethodInstance();
$methodTitle = $method->getTitle();
//print_r($method->getData());
```

**Method 2**

```
$order->getPayment()->getAdditionalInformation("method_title")
```

Comment: I've made it work with the approach that you have proposed and changing the `sales_order_save_after` to `sales_order_place_after`, thnx

Comment: glad to know .. It's helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below to get the payment method from the order.

```
$payment = $order->getPayment();
$method = $payment->getMethodInstance();
$methodTitle = $method->getTitle();
```